# Pass env var to flask via uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, debian, uwsgi

Let's say I do this on my debain install:

```
export SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=postgresql://test:test@localhost/test
```

Currently it seems flask can't read it like this:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']
```

I am starting UWSGI emperor using an Init.d script and then my app is running with emperor.

Do I need to tell uwsgi to pass this variable across so it can be read by flask, if so, how do I do that?

Comment: you did not tell when and where you call the first export. It is the whole point of the question :)

Comment: This is quite new to me, I export the env var when I deploy my server. Then I call it in the config file of my flask app.

Comment: Environment vars are set in a process and inherited by children. They are not global values. To have uwsgi and flask access them, you have to set in the init.d script